# Vaadin Crud component doesn't load data from JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin21

I'm trying to create a Webinterface for my Discord Bot which allows the User to change some Settings of the Bot on their Server.

I store those Settings using Spring JPA. The Problem is that the stored information never shows up in the Crud Component but i'm able to create new information through it.

Storage Class:

```java
@Table(name = "guild_temp_channel_settings")
@Entity
public class GuildTempChannelSettings {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private long guildId;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private long channelId;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String channelName;
}
```

Repository:

```java
public interface GuildTempChannelSettingsRepository extends JpaRepository<GuildTempChannelSettings, Long> {
    List<GuildTempChannelSettings> findByGuildId(long guildId);

}
```

DataProvider:

```java
@Slf4j
public class GuildTempChannelSettingsDataProvider extends AbstractBackEndDataProvider<GuildTempChannelSettings, CrudFilter> {
    private final GuildTempChannelSettingsRepository tempChannelSettingsRepository;
    private final long guildId;

    public GuildTempChannelSettingsDataProvider(GuildTempChannelSettingsRepository tempChannelSettingsRepository, long guildId) {
        this.tempChannelSettingsRepository = tempChannelSettingsRepository;
        this.guildId = guildId;
    }


    @Override
    protected Stream<GuildTempChannelSettings> fetchFromBackEnd(Query<GuildTempChannelSettings, CrudFilter> query) {
        int offset = query.getOffset();
        int limit = query.getLimit();

        Stream<GuildTempChannelSettings> stream = tempChannelSettingsRepository.findByGuildId(this.guildId).stream();
        log.info("Found {} entries", stream.count());

        if (query.getFilter().isPresent()) {
            stream = stream
                .filter(predicate(query.getFilter().get()))
                .sorted(comparator(query.getFilter().get()));
        }

        return stream.skip(offset).limit(limit);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeInBackEnd(Query<GuildTempChannelSettings, CrudFilter> query) {
        return tempChannelSettingsRepository.findByGuildId(this.guildId).size();
    }

    private static Predicate<GuildTempChannelSettings> predicate(CrudFilter filter) {
        // For RDBMS just generate a WHERE clause
        return filter.getConstraints().entrySet().stream()
            .map(constraint -> (Predicate<GuildTempChannelSettings>) person -> {
                try {
                    Object value = valueOf(constraint.getKey(), person);
                    return value != null && value.toString().toLowerCase()
                        .contains(constraint.getValue().toLowerCase());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .reduce(Predicate::and)
            .orElse(e -> true);
    }

    private static Comparator<GuildTempChannelSettings> comparator(CrudFilter filter) {
        return filter.getSortOrders().entrySet().stream()
            .map(sortClause -> {
                try {
                    Comparator<GuildTempChannelSettings> comparator = Comparator.comparing(settings ->
                        (Comparable) valueOf(sortClause.getKey(), settings)
                    );

                    if (sortClause.getValue() == SortDirection.DESCENDING) {
                        comparator = comparator.reversed();
                    }

                    return comparator;

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return (Comparator<GuildTempChannelSettings>) (o1, o2) -> 0;
                }
            })
            .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
            .orElse((o1, o2) -> 0);
    }

    private static Object valueOf(String fieldName, GuildTempChannelSettings person) {
        try {
            Field field = GuildTempChannelSettings.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field.get(person);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout the Crud is used in:

```java
private VerticalLayout createTemporaryChannelSettings() {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.addClassNames("box l radius", "contrast-5pct");

        Span title = new Span("Coming Soon");
        title.addClassNames("header-text", "font-size-xxl");
        layout.add(title);

        Hr titleLine = new Hr();
        layout.add(titleLine);

        Crud<GuildTempChannelSettings> crud = new Crud<>(GuildTempChannelSettings.class, createGrid(), createCrudEditor());

        GuildTempChannelSettingsDataProvider dataProvider = new GuildTempChannelSettingsDataProvider(this.guildTempChannelSettingsRepository, this.guild.getIdLong());
        crud.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
        crud.addDeleteListener(deleteEvent -> {
            //TODO delete channel
            this.guildTempChannelSettingsRepository.delete(deleteEvent.getItem());
        });
        crud.addSaveListener(saveEvent -> {
            //TODO create channel
            this.guildTempChannelSettingsRepository.save(saveEvent.getItem());
        });


        layout.add(crud);

        Html total = new Html("<span>Total: <b>" + this.guildTempChannelSettingsRepository.findByGuildId(this.guild.getIdLong()).size() + "</b> employees</span>");

        Button button = new Button("New", VaadinIcon.PLUS.create());
        button.addClickListener(event -> crud.edit(new GuildTempChannelSettings(), Crud.EditMode.NEW_ITEM));
        button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);

        HorizontalLayout toolbar = new HorizontalLayout(total, button);
        toolbar.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
        toolbar.setFlexGrow(1, toolbar);
        toolbar.setJustifyContentMode(FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.BETWEEN);
        toolbar.setSpacing(false);

        crud.setToolbar(toolbar);

        return layout;
    }
```

I've tried implementing this using the [Vaadin Crud component docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v21/ds/components/crud) but it never shows some data inside if the component. The `fetchFromBackEnd` in the DataProvider is never invoked (not sure this is important).

Am i missing something to load the information?

Edit:

I was able to fix this by adding `crud.addNewListener(newEvent -> newEvent.getItem().setGuildId(this.guild.getIdLong()));` to the Crud component. Thanks to Simon Martinelli who gave me the hint.

Sadly i'm running now into a `stream has already been operated upon or closed` [Exception](https://pastebin.com/raw/7wLyhLtp) when `fetchFromBackEnd` has been called.

I got no idea what's going on there :S

Comment: Is sizeInBackEnd called? Btw. you should call count in this method not load all data from the database and call size on it

Comment: @SimonMartinelli sizeInBackEnd is called and thank you for the hint :)

Comment: And does it return a value > 0?

Comment: tempChannelSettingsRepository.findByGuildId(this.guildId) doesn't but tempChannelSettingsRepository.count() does

Comment: @SimonMartinelli By adding a "NewListener" to my crud i was able to fix the missing guildId in the database but now i'm running into a "stream has already been operated upon or closed" exception. i'll edit my post for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue could be solved by adding `crud.addNewListener(newEvent -> newEvent.getItem().setGuildId(this.guild.getIdLong()));` to the layout.
Thanks to Simon Martinelli :)

The other issue could be solved by using a List instead of a Stream in the DataProvider `fetchFromBackEnd` method